# Invalid JSON primitive - Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying send a complex json object to my action but with no luck.

Here is my javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:52593/" + urlAction.Controller + "/" + urlAction.Action,
    type: type,
    dataType: dataType,
    data: data,
    contentType: contentType,
    async: IsAsync,
    traditional: traditional
}).done(callback);
```

Here the data object structure:

```
'"Pedido"={"Id":"null","produtos":[{"Id":6,"Quantidade":1,"Adicionais":[]}]}'
```

When I submit the ajax, I'm getting this exception:

```
Invalid JSON primitive: : {"Id":"null","produtos":[{"Id":6,"Quantidade":1,"Adicionais":[]}]}
```

I did some research in SO and did not find some way to fix it.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON object. The "root" must be an object wrapped in `{ }` as well.

Comment: What does your asp.net c# code look like?  You don't show that.

Answer (score 1):

Send `{"Id":"null","produtos":[{"Id":6,"Quantidade":1,"Adicionais":[]}]}'` as `data` instead of `'"Pedido"={"Id":"null","produtos":[{"Id":6,"Quantidade":1,"Adicionais":[]}]}'`. The latter is not valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just try this but did not work.

See it here http://prntscr.com/8un5y9

Comment: What `contentType` are you sending?

Comment: I did try 'text' and json